# Mouse-over hints in LibreOffice get cut-off

Tags: 16.04, libreoffice

I couldn't find the solve of my problem. So, problem is: in LibreOffice there are cut-off hints. I show it in the screenshot below.

[image]

Ubuntu version is 16.04.

P.S. Sorry for my English. There is Russian on the screen.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, can you report it using `ubuntu-bug libreoffice` or find an existing [bug for LibreOffice in Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice) and mark yourself as affected by that? Thanks :) And please use English in the bug report. Can you also check that if you change your language to English in 'Language Support' and if you apply it system-wide and reboot the computer, do you still get the bug?

Comment: @Ads20000: for a quick reset of the language (without effecting the whole system) maybe for screenshots and so on `LC_ALL=C libreoffice` will do the trick...

Comment: Does this happen on all hints or only if they exceed a specified width? Also is libreoffice-gtk3 installed?

Comment: @DJCrashdummy How do you revert that though?

Comment: @Ads20000: i'm not sure that i got you right... just close the application/terminal which was started and use the usual launcher/command.

Comment: @Bruni It's happen on all hints